# How to design a soft switch controlled by USB connector?

Tags: microcontroller, switches

I have to design a powerbank. I want the DC-DC boost converter (Texas Instruments TPS61090) ENable PIN set to 1 when the user plugs in the USB male connector into the female one. When the user disconnects the cable, the IC shuts down. I thought this design in order to remove the need of a switch that controls the power.

1. Is a µcontroller needed for this application?
2. If so, can you suggest one that has µpower needs?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a µcontroller if you use Micro-USB sockets and cables, because they have an additional ID pin that connects to 0V when the plug is inserted. A simple transistor inverter will convert the connection to 0V into a logic high signal that you can use to turn on your converter.

This approach gives you the option of using a Micro-AB socket on your powerbank to act as the output port to your device or for connecting a power supply to charge the battery. It's the approach adopted by many devices nowadays such as tablets and smartphones.

Comment: Thank you. May you please sketch the circuit?

Comment: Powerbanks nearly always have USB A female sockets on though.

Comment: I'll leave you to draw the circuit but a simple PNP switch with emitter connected to your positive supply, collector to the EN pin and base pulled down to 0V through a resistor by the connector pin will do the job. Add a pulldown on the EN pin to 0V and a pullup to positive on the base.

Comment: @Finbarr Will it also work with the micro to Lightning adapter? I can't find the adapter pinout anywhere.

Comment: The connection from the ID pin to 0V is made inside the Micro A plug, so yes - as long as the cable to the adapter has a Micro A plug on the end it should work.